# How to verify Spring LDAP connection pooling configuration?

Tags: java, spring, ldap, connection-pooling, spring-ldap

I have configured LDAP connection pooling in a Spring boot application for LDAP searches (not LDAP binds). Here is my LDAP configuration:

```
@Bean
public ContextSource poolingLdapContextSource() {

    PoolingContextSource poolingContextSource = new PoolingContextSource();
    poolingContextSource.setDirContextValidator(new DefaultDirContextValidator());
    poolingContextSource.setContextSource(ldapContextSource());

    return poolingContextSource;
}


@Bean
public LdapContextSource ldapContextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrls(ldapUrls.toArray(new String[]{}));
    contextSource.setUserDn(ldapUsername);
    contextSource.setPassword(ldapPassword);
    contextSource.setPooled(false);

    return contextSource;
}


@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new LdapTemplate(poolingLdapContextSource());
}
```

I have enabled debug logging in application.yml as follows:

org.springframework.ldap: debug

org.springframework.ldap.pool: debug

In the logs I see the following:

`17-10-10 16:11:12:976 DEBUG o.s.l.c.s.AbstractContextSource - AuthenticationSource not set - using default implementation
2017-10-10 16:11:12:976 DEBUG o.s.l.c.s.AbstractContextSource - **Not using LDAP pooling**
2017-10-10 16:11:12:976 DEBUG o.s.l.c.s.AbstractContextSource - Trying provider Urls: ldap://xxx:389 ldap://yyy:389`

Questions:

1. Why does log say "Not using LDAP pooling"?
2. How to get more detailed logging regarding pooling, to get more insight into when Spring opens a new connection, how many active connections exist, etc.?

Comment: The connection pool can be handled natively by ldap driver itself and you will enable it by setting `contextSource.setPooled(true);`
In your code you set it to false (which is the recommended value when using spring-ldap) then the AbstractContextSource tells you he will not use the LDAP pooling.

I do not know how to have more log message but I can monitor that with the thread using jconsole.

Comment: Still the same issue in spring security 5.1.3. Only slightly confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Might not help you now after a year or more but even with TRACE, no more logging comes out of `org.springframework.ldap` or `org.springframework.security`.

You could prove it to yourself in another couple of ways.

- don't provide the non-pooled `LdapContextSource`. Just provide it programmatically to `PoolingContextSource.setContextSource()`
- run the server in debug and put a break-point in `PoolingContextSource.getContext()`.